# Showing images using prettyphoto onclick of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

I have a ul list of images as follows:

```
<ul class="thumbs">
    <li><a href="#" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <li><a href="#" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</ul>
```

I bind prettyphoto event as follows which works fine for gallary.

```
 $("a[rel='prettyPhoto[pp_gal]']").prettyPhoto({ social_tools: false, slideshow: false });
```

I have another anchor tag on my page as follows:

```
 <a href="#">View all images</a>
```

how can I bind pretty photo event such that onclick of viewall , images from ul get show up just same as they appear on click of any image from ul list.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on localhost, and this works for me: (according to your example)

```
    <a href="#" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]">View all images</a>
```

Of curse, href should point to some image.

Comment: thanx for your kind reply. but i have already tried this. and when i click on view all images. it gives error because it do not find image path in href. and if i gave give imagepath of first image in href then it repeats that image two times. :(